# Como tomo o obtengo un 1 solo valor de 2 parámetros en una funciona

Tags: python

estoy aprendiendo a programar con python y tengo un problema quiero obtener un solo valor de una función con 2 parametros es decir:

```
def crearPersonaje(nombre, vida, ataque):
    nombrePersonaje = nombre
    vidaPersonaje = vida
    ataquePersonaje = ataque

jose = crearPersonaje("Jose", 100 ,75)
jose.nombrePersonaje
```

quiero escoger el nombre del personaje es decir que me devuelva el string Jose

el error que me salta:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Franco/Desktop/tst.py", line 8, in <module>
    jose.nombrePersonaje
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'nombrePersonaje'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar self si usas objetos.

```
class CrearPersonaje:
    def __init__(self, nombre, vida, ataque):
        self.nombrePersonaje = nombre
        vidaPersonaje = vida
        ataquePersonaje = ataque

jose = CrearPersonaje("Jose", 100 ,75)
jose.nombrePersonaje
```

Comment: Donde se colocaría el self?

Comment: échale un vistazo al código revisado.

Comment: Ah, jajajaja no lo vi

Comment: Una duda, para utilizar el self si o si hay que crear una clase no?

Comment: Así es. Debe ser una clase.